# Use database in the Firefox web extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to use some database in my Firefox web extension, I already found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage), but it's just a storage for key-value pairs.

So how can I use database in the Firefox web extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the IndexedDB Web API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

There's a [sample extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/store-collected-images) that uses it, though it's using a library. It might be better to look at general [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) examples.

You probably want to declare `"unlimitedStorage"` permission; in Chrome, it lifts the 5MB restriction on size, while on Firefox it apparently [bypasses a user prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Unlimited_storage).

Note that IndexedDB is per-origin, so your content scripts (whose origin is technically the page they are running in) won't be able to access it directly; you'll need to rely on Messaging to let the background page "proxy" the access.