# Use some kind of database in webextension firefox

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Suppose i want to create some firefox extension like scrapBook and for storing scraped data use database like sqlite (what was possible in addon-sdk) is there any way to do this? The best solution for me is store information in sqlite. This addon, i plane to use myself, so don't have any security limitations, but still there must be a way to do it, as according to oficial documentation (or maybe i not look well) there is only IndexedDB with some size limitations.

Comment: There's not enough explanation of your requirements, but it's probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53293160/934239

Comment: actually what i want is store information in sqlite this addon, i plane to use myself, so don't have any security limitations, but still there must be a way to do it, as according to oficial documentation (or maybe i not look well) there is only IndexedDB  with some size limitations.

Comment: Please clarify that in the question then by editing it.

Comment: done, but it is not seems possible

Comment: Please note that size limitations will be mostly gone (to the tune of 2GB) if you declare `"unlimitedStorage"` permission.